# Grpc Middleware or Interceptors in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, metadata, middleware, grpc

I'm implementing a grpc service in C# and I'm trying to figure out if I can use some sort of middleware for authentication.

I've searched wide and the best I've come up with is that, some sort of interceptors are available in java and go, but are internal in C# (I saw this in the code as well).

I'm using jwt tokens and would like to pass them via metadata and validate them per call.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: For anyone looking at this question, as at the time of asking this, middleware are not supported in the C-Core versions of GRPC. They are there, but are an internal implementation detail. You can find them in Java and Go however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a pull request which adds support for C# Interceptors, which looks like it has potential to be merged. It was discussed in the gRPC community meeting on 2017-09-28: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DTMEbBNmzNbZBh8nOivsnnw3CwUr1Q7WGRe7rNxyHOU

https://github.com/grpc/proposal/pull/38